# Multiple declaration in for loop

Tags: c++

I have the following defined in my program

```
int row;
int col;

for(int k = 1; k <= sizestr1; k++){
  for(row = k, col = 1; (row == 0 && col <= sizestr2); row-- , col++){

        //logic here
    }
}
```

Upon debugging, the logic in the inner loop doesn't seem to be executing. Is the definition of the above inner loop valid in C++

Comment: `row == 0` is always FALSE.

Comment: `row` never gets the value `0`. Did you mean to write `row != 0` instead of `row == 0`?

Comment: I guess syntactically valid (what say Your compiler?) but hard to understand logic, for example variable row. Suppose You have important warnings (uninitialised variables), such give IMPORTANT runtime (algorithmic) errors

Comment: @JacekCz Both `row` and `col` are initialized at the beginning of the inner loop: `row = k, col = 1`.

Comment: @CiaPan Agree, must don't read hard code in the middle of the night ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the outer loop `k` starts from `1` and goes upwards., so it never gets the value of `0`. And the inner loop requires `row == 0` (in conjunction with `col <= sizestr2`). So the inner loop's condition is never satisfied, hence the inner loop body is never executed.

The conditional expression determines when the loop is *allowed* to execute, so you need to test if the variable is *non-negative* to allow looping:

```
int row;
int col;

for(int k = 1; k <= sizestr1; k++){
    for(row = k, col = 1; row >= 0 && col <= sizestr2; row-- , col++){

        //logic here
    }
}
```

As an alternative you can test the `row` variable for negative value *inside* the loop an break the loop respectively:

```
int row;
int col;

for(int k = 1; k <= sizestr1; k++){
    for(row = k, col = 1; col <= sizestr2; row-- , col++){
        if(row < 0)
            break;      // terminate the inner loop

        //logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: yep i missed out on that, i want to terminate that inner loop when row value is less than 0

Comment: @RRP Please see the expanded answer.